# How do you map 2 different tables with different PKs to the same class?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 almost identical tables representing the same class. The only difference is the 2nd table has a 2 column primary key as opposed to 1 column.
id vs id and version
The first table represents the current state of the objects while the 2nd table contains the complete history that is maintained via triggers (perhaps the only time I think triggers are okay). 
I'm using Spring Boot w/ Spring Data JPA and hibernate as the ORM. I want to be able to query the history table for a complete history of an object by id and query by id and version. 
I was hoping (in vain) I could do something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
public Class Page {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;
    //...
}

public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, Integer> {
    // Some current page specific methods...

    @Query(value = "select * from page_history where id = :pageId order by version asc", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Page> findHistory(@Param("pageId") Integer pageId);

    //...
}
```

Unfortunately when I call findHistory Hibernate it recognizes the id column as the primary key so when there are multiple records in the ResultSet with the same id, it uses the 1st level Session cache and returns the same object multiple times.

Is there a way to do what I want ideally without creating 2 identical classes with different mappings?

Answer (score 1):

"Almost identical tables" != "identical tables". If you need to normalize your database then you can use Inheritance, making a base class and extending it with Entities that hold the differences. However, I don't think that trying to manipulate JPA in order to compensate for database issues is a good idea. Better either to fix the database or just make two separate entities.

Comment: The java objects are the same so using inheritance is a hack. The constraints are different since the 1st table contains only 1 (the current) version of a record while the 2nd contains the complete history of a record. Therefore the PK on table 1 is just the ID and the PK on table 2 is the ID and Version (version exists in both tables).
I don't see this as a DB design issue, but just something that doesn't seem to be supported in JPA. I might just need to go lower level and write the sql and read from the result set myself.